# Motorbike problem with power

Tags: engine, clutch, gears

Hi guys I got problem with my 125cc bike.. actually the engine run fine think is soon i put the first gear on and give up the clutch the bike is like try to go but unbelievable slowly even when I open more the throttle no reaction somebody know what the problem can be i think clutch is gone but I'm not sure if somebody know anything about it pls help thank you very much Danny.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to MVM&R. When you let out the clutch, does the engine load down as usual, or is it as if you hadn't really let out the clutch?

Answer (score 1):

Check on the clutch lever for an knurled adjustment type screw thread, loosen the lock nut and screw the knurled thread in towards the brake lever a couple of turns, this should take any tension that's in the cable away, allowing the clutch to bite again. 
After adjustment If this still doesn't happen and the engine just revs but there is no drive, its likely that the clutch may require replacement.